# How to use databricks cluster to run airflow PythonOperator?

Tags: python, airflow, databricks, azure-databricks, orchestration

I have a customized function inside the python script that represents the airflow dag. The dag uses the PythonOperator to run this custom function. I want this task to be run on databricks cluster and not through local compute. Is that possible?

**Note**
I tried exploring the following databricks operators:

1. DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
2. DatabricksRunNowOperator

It seems both of the operators are useful only to run a databricks notebook. But, I don't want my custom function to be written in databricks notebook.

Please let me know if you need more information?

Comment: I am not an expert but have a look at this: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit , It looks like you can pass other values as well besides notebook

Comment: And observing source code: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/databricks_operator.html
Find: `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` their comment and implementation allows different parameter as well

Comment: Thanks! I had a quick view and URLs makes sense. May be, python_params of DatabricksRunNow operator can do the job. One thing I need to figure out is how to use 2.0/jobs/runs/submit endpoint as I haven't done things like this before.